# how to handle optional value in rest api post in Msflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

Hi i am updating people picker , managed metadata column in SharePoint using powerautoamte send http request to Sharepoint now few fields is optional when this fields go empty it throw error , how can we handle this type of value below is my Rest call body

Method is post

```
        {
        "formValues": [
        {"FieldName":"Business","FieldValue":'@{items('Apply_to_each_2')['Business']['Value']}'},
        {"FieldName":"TwoBusiness","FieldValue":'@{items('Apply_to_each_2')['TwoBusiness']['Value']}'},
        {"FieldName":"Discipline","FieldValue":'@{items('Apply_to_each_2')['Discipline']['Value']}'},
        {"FieldName":"Country","FieldValue":'@{variables('CountryMetadata')}'},
        {"FieldName":"Process","FieldValue":'@{variables('Process')}'},
        {"FieldName":"Asset","FieldValue":'@{variables('Asset')}'},
        {"FieldName":"SAEFLanguage","FieldValue":'@{items('Apply_to_each_2')['SAEFLanguage']['Value']}'},
        {"FieldName":"SAEFDocumentType","FieldValue":'@{items('Apply_to_each_2')['SAEFDocumentType']['Value']}'}
        ],
        "bNewDocumentUpdate":false,
        "checkInComment":null
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The steps and screenshots below show how to update multi-value People Picker (Person Type) column using REST API in Power Automate.

1. Examine user ids in the hidden **User Information List** by a REST API call.
   These Ids will be used to update **Approver** column. The corresponding internal name of the updating property would be **ApproverId**.

[image]

2. Once ids are identified, use POST Methods to create new items or update existing items

[image]

3. To remove all users from **Approver** column (set to null), use the following

[image]